# Delete columns based on header value VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to delete columns that contain the text "Title" from all the Worksheets. (It could be Title A, Title B, etc.) 
I wrote the below, but it's not working... Please enlighten me.

```
Dim wsh As Worksheet
Dim A As Range

For Each wsh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    Do
        Set A = Rows(1).Find(What:="Title", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart)
        If A Is Nothing Then Exit Do
        A.EntireColumn.Delete
    Loop
Next wsh
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are looking for "Title A" (as well for only "Title") , you can use the `Find` in 2 ways:

- Add the `*` wild-card to the searched string, and at the third parameter have xlWhole `Find(What:="Title*", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)`
- Don't use the `*` wild-card, and use xlPart  `.Find(What:="Title", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart)`

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub RemoveTitle()

Dim wsh As Worksheet
Dim A As Range

For Each wsh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    Do
        Set A = wsh.Rows(1).Find(What:="Title", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart)
        If Not A Is Nothing Then
            A.EntireColumn.Delete
        End If

    Loop While Not A Is Nothing
Next wsh

End Sub
```

Comment: actually the `lookat:=xlPart` parameter suffices to avoid the use of `*` in `What`

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation!

Comment: @Kenji you're welcome , mark as answer (click the **V** next to my answer)

Answer (score 0):

You are not qualifying your range with a sheet so only the active sheet is searched

```
Sub x()

Dim wsh As Worksheet
Dim A As Range

For Each wsh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    Do
        Set A = wsh.Rows(1).Find(What:="Title", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart)
        If A Is Nothing Then Exit Do
        A.EntireColumn.Delete
    Loop
Next wsh

End Sub
```

Comment: Overlooked that! What a basic mistake :0 Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the sheet in which you use `Find`
And add `*` (wildcard) to include all possibilities

```
Dim wsh As Worksheet
Dim A As Range
For Each wsh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    Do
        Set A = wsh.Rows(1).Find(What:="Title*", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart)
        If A Is Nothing Then Exit Do
        A.EntireColumn.Delete
    Loop
Next wsh
```

Comment: I see, this wildcard is very useful! Thank You!

Comment: @Kenji : Glad I could help! ;) Take a minute to take a tour and discover how SO works : http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

you may want to delete all columns in one shot

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim wsh As Worksheet
    Dim A As Range, foundTitle As Range
    Dim firstAddress As String

    For Each wsh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        With wsh.Range("A1", wsh.Cells(1, wsh.Cells.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
            Set foundTitle = .Offset(1).Resize(1, 1)
            Set A = .Find(What:="Title", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart)
            If Not A Is Nothing Then
                firstAddress = A.Address
                Do
                    Set foundTitle = Union(foundTitle, A)
                    Set A = .FindNext(A)
                Loop While A.Address <> firstAddress
            End If
            Set foundTitle = Intersect(foundTitle, .Cells)
            If Not foundTitle Is Nothing Then foundTitle.EntireColumn.Delete
        End With
    Next wsh
End Sub
```

Comment: This gave me a error of "Delete method of Range class failed" at the 4th line from the last...

Comment: In my tests it worked! What's the data "face" that gave you that error?